# Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

The browser:

Show Error Message :

`Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php`

But in other Controllers working fine. 
I did move site from Codeigniter 2.x to 3.x.
After that this error occurred.

When I print my session with this `$this->session->all_userdata()` code the output showing session data.

What I do for resolve this error.

Comment: add your controller code so we can have a look.

Comment: @Kevin I found error i.e. I have called another controller like `require('****.php')`. the session library called two times in same file.

Comment: You can set in the autoload.php   $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');

Comment: Where is this error show? Means in controller or model?

Comment: @AnandPandey error showing in controller. I am  trying to use another controller's method in main controller. That's why I added controller1.php file in controller2.php.

Comment: So you have to load session in constructor of controller $this->load->library('session'); or in autoload.php

Answer (score 0):

Add changes in application/config/autoload.php file

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

and in config

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'pqrstuxyz';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Codeigniter Modular Extensions HMVC** this error can occur if you forget to change your class to extend **MX_Controller** instead of **CI_Controller**

Simply Change your extended Class as following

```
Class YourController extends CI_Controller
```

to

```
Class YourController extends MX_Controller
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you made own models? You probably extend a model with the CI_Controller like this:

```
class Some_model extends CI_Controller
```

It should extend the CI_Model:

```
class Some_model extends CI_Model
```